# How to simplify many "If Then Else" queries?

Tags: vba, if-statement

Can you give me a hint on how to make such code more elegant?

I need some more of these queries in the future and I would like to do it more professionally.

Thank you!

```
       If Case = "V" Then
            Case Is = "Sal"
        Else
            If Case = "K" Then
                Case Is = "Dep"
            Else
                If Case = "A" Then
                    Case Is = "Auf"
                Else
                    If Case = "M" Then
                        Case Is = "Mon"
                    Else
                        If Case = "T" Then
                            Case Is = "Tec"
                        Else
                            If Case = "W" Then
                                Case Is = "Ver"
                            Else
                                If Case = "B" Then
                                    Case Is = "Ber"
                                Else
                                    If Case = "P" Then
                                        Case Is = "Ver"
                                    Else
                                        GoTo GoNext
                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `Select Case`

---

```
Sub test()

Dim strCode     As String
Dim strVal      As String

strCode = "B"

Select Case strCode
    Case "A"
        strVal = "Jan"
    Case "B"
        strVal = "Feb"
    Case "C"
        strVal = "Mar"
    Case Else
        strVal = "No match found"
End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `Select Case ... End Select`

But you need to declare a variable, let us say `x` to be the reference

```
Dim x as String, y as String

'Allocate value to the `x` variable. In any way. Then:

Select Case x
   Case "V": y = "Sal"
   Case "K": y = "Dep"
   Case "A": y = "Auf"

   ' and so  on...

   Case Else: y = "Whatever..."   
End Select
```

Finally you obtain the `y` value according to the `x` one...

Answer (score 2):

As usual, multiple ifs are simplified into one dictionary / hash table / object .

```
Dim variablename
Set variablename = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
variablename.Add ("V", "Sal")
variablename.Add ("K", "Dep")
....
variablename.Add ("P", "Var")
```

Get the variable as follows

```
ans = 'Nothing' 
if variablename.exists("P") then 
    ans = variablename("P")
    Rem ans = variablename.item("P") ?
    Rem Equals "Var"
end if
```

see also https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/

Answer (score 1):

What about the following:

```
  If Case = "V" Then

  ElseIf Case = "K" Then

  ElseIf Case = "A" Then

  ...

  End If
```